# How do I combine both searching and filtering tableViewCells in the same viewController?

Tags: swift

I have a viewController displaying products in a given product group, and in that VC i have both a searchBar and a special filtering solution, and I'm struggling with the best approach to make them both work seemlessly side-by-side.

[image]

I've only implemented inStock for now, and it works, but I want the filters and the searchBar to work on top of each other.

#### Example data:

```swift
let products = [Product]() {
return [ 
Product(name: "Apple", stock: 5),
Product(name: "AppleJuice", stock: 5),
Product(name: "Orange", stock: 0),
Product(name: "baskedOfApples", stock: 0) ]
```

#### How it works now:

Searching for Apple shows index 0,1,3 --> Adding filter "In Stock" removes index 3. --> removing  the filter doesn't do anything as the final array that is shown is a result of multiple copies because of a filter

#### Suggestion:

Since the searching/filtering is done based on different delegate-methods, is it a valid approach to have a base array with all products, then create a filteredProducts[] and searchedProducts[], and then have a final displayedProducts[] that is all items that are present in both arrays? My concern is that it would be heavy to loop to compare those two for every search/filter update?

#### Present Code:

```swift
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    var productsInSelectedCategoryGroup = [Product]()
    private var searchedProducts = [Product]()
    private var filteredProducts = [Product]()
    private var searchController = FUISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    private var filterFeedbackControl: FUIFilterFeedbackControl!
    private var categoryGroup = FUIFilterGroup()
    
    private var displayedProducts: [Product] {
        if isSearching() {
            return searchedProducts
        } else if !filterFeedbackControl.filterItems.filter({ $0.isActive }).isEmpty {
            return filteredProducts
        } else {
            return productsInSelectedCategoryGroup
        }
    }
```

```swift
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return displayedProducts.count
    }
```

```swift
    func isSearching() -> Bool {
        return searchController.isActive && !searchTextIsEmpty()
    }

    func searchProducts(_ searchText: String) {
        
        let productsToSearch = !filterFeedbackControl.filterItems.filter({ $0.isActive }).isEmpty ? filteredProducts : productsInSelectedCategoryGroup

        searchedProducts = productsToSearch.filter( {(product : Product) -> Bool in
            return product.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

```swift
extension ProductsViewController: FUIFilterResultsUpdating {
    
    func updateFilterResults(for filterFeedbackControl: FUIFilterFeedbackControl) {
        
        let productsToFilter = isSearching() ? searchedProducts : productsInSelectedCategoryGroup
        filteredProducts.removeAll()
        let activeFilterItems = filterFeedbackControl.filterItems.filter({ $0.isActive })
        if !activeFilterItems.isEmpty {
            
            for filterItem in categoryGroup.items {
                if activeFilterItems.contains(filterItem) {
                    let _filteredProducts = productsToFilter.filter {(product: Product) in
                        
                        switch filterItem.key {
                        case AccessibilityIdentifier.inStockFilterFeedbackKey.rawValue:
                            return product.storeStock > 1
                        default:
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                    filteredProducts.append(contentsOf: _filteredProducts)
                }
            }
        } else {
            filteredProducts = productsToFilter
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: What about combining the two delegates into a third one (which would handle both) and you VC will handle only the third one. Where the third one, could asks the others for the filters (you could use an array of closures to use on filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different filter functions for each search/filter criteria and then apply them using an array and `filter`

```
typealias ProductFilter = (Product) -> Bool
var searchKey: String! //just for this example
var newDate: Date! //just for this example, not sure what New filter means

let nameFilter: ProductFilter = { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchKey) }
let stockFilter: ProductFilter = { $0.stock > 0 }
let discontinuedFilter: ProductFilter = { $0.discontinued }
let newFilter: ProductFilter = {$0.date > newDate}
```

and then applying the filter using the search key

```
let filterArray = [nameFilter, stockFilter]

searchKey = "app"
let filtered = products.filter { product in
    filterArray.first(where: {!$0(product)}) == nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joakim Danielson! That was a nice touch! Still, I need to make sure they're updated each time a filter is changed or the searchString changes. Any suggestions on how to proceed with that? Empty'ing the array each time doesn't seem like the best option, as one method is called when changes to filters and another when changes to the searchString. Removing the array in either will remove the effect of both..

Comment: @perage Add above to a function and every time a filter is changed in the UI you re-build the `filterArray` and perform a new search by calling that function and same when the searchString changes. You only need 2 arrays, one for all products and one that holds the result of the last call to the function

Comment: Ok! I though that would be to heavy to compute, but I think I just have to get used to the fact that it is a power machine doing this :D I’m used to ABAP and SQL programming - have to take performance into consideration a lot :)